# Passing unspecialized template as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, stl, metaprogramming

Can i do something like

```
template<class Key, class Data, class Compare = less<Key>, template<typename T> class Allocator<T> = allocator<T> >
    class mymap {
        typedef map<Key,Data,Compare,Allocator<pair<const Key, Data> > > storageMap; 
        typedef vector<Data,Allocator<Data> > storageVector;
}
```

So template is passed to the class unspecialiazed and instantiated later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, here's a minimal compileable example:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <
    class Key,
    class Data,
    class Compare = less<Key>,
    template <typename T> class Allocator = allocator
>
class mymap
{
public:
    typedef map<Key,Data,Compare,Allocator<pair<const Key, Data> > > storageMap; 
    typedef vector<Data,Allocator<Data> > storageVector;
};

int main()
{
    mymap<int,long>::storageMap m;
    mymap<int,long>::storageVector v;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called a "template-template parameter", and the syntax is

```
template <class Key, class Data, class Compare = less<Key>,
          template <typename T> class Allocator = allocator >
class mymap {
    typedef map<Key,Data,Compare,Allocator<pair<const Key, Data> > > storageMap; 
    typedef vector<Data,Allocator<Data> > storageVector;
}
```

Comment: `code`mymap.hpp(30): error: identifier "T" is undefined
      template<class Key, class Data, class Policy = policy_none<Key>, class Compare = less<Key>, template<typename T> class Allocator = allocator<T> > `code`  @mmutz well, gcc isn't happy with such declaration :)

Comment: @akashi: `s/= allocator<T>/= allocator/

Comment: my fault, sorry  Thanks for assistance