# Passing Map Implementation through Templates

Tags: c++, templates, stl, polymorphism

I have a class that stores two maps like so:

```
class Database {
    std::map<A,B> map1;
    std::map<C,A> map2;
};
```

I have just included part of the class. `Database` has more functions and data elements that I have not included.

I want to change the implementation of map from `std::map` to something else that has the same public interface. This seems to be a good place for templating.

Normally, I would write `template<class Map>` at the top and be done. However, there are a problem.

Map is not specialized within this class. For example, if I just need a Map. Writing template would be fine. I would define 'Database' as `Database<std::map<A, B>>`. However, I need two separate map instances.

Do I need to write `template<class Map1, class Map2>` and define 'Database' as `Database<std::map<A, B>>`? **Or is there a better way of doing the templated definition. Or are templates the wrong technique for this situation?**

Ideally, I would like to be able to write `Database<std::map>`. **Is this possible?**

I had previously checked:

[Error when pass std::map as template template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32289677/error-when-pass-stdmap-as-template-template-argument)

[Error passing map to template function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327393/error-passing-map-to-template-function-in-c)

[Passing unspecialized template as a template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745345/passing-unspecialized-template-as-a-template-parameter)

However, these two not really deal with my problem of having two different parameterizations.

EDIT:
Overall, I am trying to specify the implementation of map for Database. I want to be able to write Database or Database and have the map elements of Database be implemented in the specified way.

Comment: Why was I downvoted?

Comment: What are you *trying* to do here? You're talking a lot about possible solutions, but not about your problem.

Comment: I am trying to specify the implementation of map for Database. I want to be able to write Database<std::map> or Database<custom_map> and have the map elements of Database be implemented in the specified way.

Comment: I'm not sure you're tackling this problem the right way. Templates are trouble. Why not have a base class of some kind with a well-defined interface, then store that as a pointer so you can pass in an arbitrary subclass.

Comment: I considered that. However, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829860/what-is-the-c-equivalent-of-inheriting-a-java-collection-interface-set-map?rq=1 seemed to indicate that templates were a more idiomatic solution.

Comment: That depends on what object-oriented design school of thinking you're using. C++ templates *can* be powerful, but if they're the only tool you ever use they can easily be abused.

Comment: However, std::map does not have any interface that I know of. So I do not think I can make pass an interface pointer.

Comment: I'm talking about making an abstract base class that implements an interface like `std::map`.

Comment: I understand that. But how would I pass std::map to Database if it has no connection to the abstract base class. Moreover, I would have to pass two pointers one for each map, which is not an improvement over just passing two templated types.

Comment: It's an improvement if you can get it working within the limitations of C++. You really need to try and make this happen. Your question here is missing some experimentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for template template parameters. Something like this:

```
template <template <class...> class Map>
class Database {
    Map<A, B> map1;
    Map<C, A> map2;
};

Database<std::map> dbOnStdMap;
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/EXQGI45566)